# In bash, environmental variables not tab-expanding correctly

Tags: bash, unix, keyboard-shortcuts

In bash, environmental variables will tab-expand correctly when placed after an echo command, for example:

```
echo $HOME
```

But after cd or cat, bash places a \ before the $ sign, like so:

```
cd \$HOME
```

If I use a variable as the second argument to a command, it won't expand at all:

```
cp somefile $HOM
```

What mysterious option do I have in my .bashrc or .inputrc file that is causing me such distress?

Comment: Scripting IS programming!

Comment: It would be very helpful to know which Linux distribution or which variant of Unix you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ***complete -r cd*** to remove the special programmatic completion function that many Linux distributions install for the `cd` command. The function adds searching a list of of directories specified in the CDPATH variable to tab completions for `cd`, but at the expense of breaking the default completion behavior.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion for more gory details.

Answer (score 5):

What you're describing is a "feature" [introduced in bash 4.2](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00274.html). So you don't have any mysterious option causing you distress, but just "intended" behaviour.

I find this very annoying since I preferred it the way it used to be and haven't found any configuration options yet to get the earlier behaviour back. Playing with `complete` options as suggested by other answers didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: This is the correct answer; the stuff about auto-completion is fixing a symptom, not the cause. A "direxpand" shopt is on its way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

For the second instance, you can press ESC before tab to solve it.

I don't know the solution to your problem, but you could look in **/etc/bash_completion** or the files under **/etc/bash_completion.d** to determine what commands use autocompletion and how.

```
help complete
```

Might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[The Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) has more information than you might want on expansion errata.

[Section 8.7](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) looks like it would be the place to start.  It give information on the 'complete' function, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer for 
https://superuser.com/questions/434139/urxvt-tab-expand-environment-variables by Dmitry Alexandrov:

> This is about direxpand option. **`$ shopt -s direxpand`** and `$FOO_PATH/` will be expanded by TAB.

Comment: The question is about expanding `$FOO_` to `$FOO_PATH`, not about expanding `$FOO_PATH` to its contents. However, this answer is useful, too.

Comment: Richard is correct.... but I mistakenly found this answer  (after misunderstanding the OP's question) and it was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering 4-year-old question! Fantastic!

This is a bash bug/feature which was unintentionally introduced in v4.2, and was unnoticed for a long period of time. This was pointed out by geirha in [this tread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41891/bash-auto-complete-for-environment-variables). Confirmed as unintended feature [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00296.html)

I came across this problem when running Ubuntu at home. At work I have bash-3.00, so I've spent some time browsing around to see what's going on. I wonder if I can 'downgrade'....